# Can't read Blob Image - Ionic 3 / Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, api, ionic-framework

I got a dump problem.

I uploaded an Image manually as Longblob on my MySQL Database as shown:

[image]

Now I try to display that Image in my Hybrid Ionic 3 / Angular 4 App in my Template:

```
<img *ngIf="user.image" ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{user.image}}" >
```

When I look up my Network Traffic in Chrome I only see an empty Image as shown:

[image]

For Information: the `user.image` is from type Buffer as and Array.

Why doesn't it show my Blob-Image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! Thanks Kannaiyan, you were right, it was in the wrong format. Now I try to read the DataURL from the File input:

```
<input class="fileInput" style="display:none;" type="file" (change)="getBase64()">
```

In Typescript:

```
getBase64() {
let input = $(".fileInput").get(0);
let b64;
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

  var reader= new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
  b64 = reader.result;
}
this.user.image = b64;
}
```

First thanks: If I paste my output to my img tag it shows the image, but the curious thing is, if I `console.log(reader.result)`, it prints the right DataURL, but if I try to get the DataURL in my `user.image` variable it says there's nothing / undefined... could you explain that? Could it be a security reason on Ionic/Angular?

Comment: You are welcome. I think you might have a scope issue. Hardcode the value to user.image directly to see if that takes the value and displays the image in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Thats doesn't makes sense.. why you are saving base64 URL.. Try to store normal URL in blob and then while retrieving convert it into base64.. As base64 URLs are converted into too long URL so its obvious your server will show error.. and we cant decide length of URL so we cannot define size for base64 URL while creating db for it.

Hope you get my point!

Answer (score 0):

The encoded data is not a Buffer of type array. Instead the binary data is encoded into base 64 format.

http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker

The above url helps to convert the binary data to base 64 format.

When you store in the MySQL database, you need to store it the encoded data as it is.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried to answer you directly, but my Post goes above yours. Please read above :). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it:

```
function getBase64(event) {

  let input = $("#fileInput").get(0).files[0];

  if (input) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(input);
    reader.onloadend = (e) => {
      console.log(btoa(reader.result));
      $("#img").attr('src','data:' + input.type + ';base64,' + btoa(reader.result));
      $("#source").attr('value', 'data:' + input.type + ';base64,' + btoa(reader.result));
    };
  };
}
```

I couldn't get the Base64-DataURL in Typescript/Angular, so i outsourced my getBase64() function to my index.html and triggered it with another hidden input tag to pass the base64 chars to my this.user.image variable.

But now if I try to Post via: `http.post('/uploadUserProfileImage', this.user, {headers: headers}) {...}` I get an "**PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large**" Error in my NodeJS Server. And yes I already increased the allowed bodyParser Limits to 50mb. But that's another question for an other Post :).

Thanks again!